# Trouble with minimax algorithm in tic tac toe game with adjustable game size

Tags: python, minimax

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game with an adjustable game size and a computer that uses the minimax algorithm. The game sizes can only be odd numbers, to make sure that diagonal wins are always possible. The game runs with no errors, but I know that the minimax algorithm isn't working 100% correct because I can still beat the computer. I've looked extensively over my code and cannot find where the algorithm is going wrong. Here is my code:

**Main.py**

```
import TicTacToe
import Minimax

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    t = TicTacToe.ttt(3)
    m = Minimax.Minimax(3, t)
    
    while (t.winner == None):
        if (t.turn == 1):
            playerInputI = int(input("Input row: "))
            playerInputJ = int(input("Input column: "))
            bestIndex = (playerInputI, playerInputJ)
        else:
            winner, bestIndex = m.minimax(t.grid, (-1, -1), 15, -1)
            t.winner = None
            t.findWinner(bestIndex, t.grid)
            

        t.updateGameGrid(bestIndex)
        print(t.grid)

    print(t.grid)
```

**Minimax.py**

```
class Minimax:
    def __init__(self, gs, t):
        self.gridSize = gs
        self.ttt = t

    def minimax(self, state, currIndex, depth, turn):
        if (currIndex[0] != -1 and currIndex[1] != -1):
            winner = self.ttt.findWinner(currIndex, state)

            if (winner == -1):
                return winner - depth, currIndex
            elif (winner == -1):
                return winner + depth, currIndex
            elif (winner == 0):
                return 0, currIndex

            if (depth==0 and winner==None):
                return 0, currIndex
        
        evalLimit = -turn * 1000
        bestIndex = None
        for i in range(self.gridSize):
            for j in range(self.gridSize):
                if (state[i][j] == 0):
                    state[i][j] = turn

                    eval, newIndex = self.minimax(state, (i, j), depth-1, -turn)
                    state[i][j] = 0
                    if (turn > 0 and eval > evalLimit):
                        bestIndex = newIndex
                        evalLimit = eval
                    elif (turn < 0 and eval < evalLimit):
                        bestIndex = newIndex
                        evalLimit = eval
        
        return evalLimit, bestIndex
```

**Tictactoe.py**

```
from random import randint

class ttt:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.gridSize = size
        self.grid = self.createGrid()

        # If using minimax algorithm, user is maximizer(1) and computer is minimizer(-1)
        # If single player, then user is 1, computer is -1
        # If multiplayer, user1 is 1, user2 = -1
        self.turn = 1
        self.winner = None

    def createGrid(self):
        grid = []
        for i in range(self.gridSize):
            grid.append([])
            for j in range(self.gridSize):
                grid[i].append(0)


        # grid = [[-1, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

        return grid

    def updateGameGrid(self, index):
        if (self.grid[index[0]][index[1]] != 0):
            return

        self.grid[index[0]][index[1]] = self.turn
        winner = self.findWinner(index, self.grid)  

        self.turn = -self.turn
        
    def randomIndex(self):
        x = randint(0, self.gridSize-1)
        y = randint(0, self.gridSize-1)
        while (self.grid[x][y] != 0):
            x = randint(0, self.gridSize-1)
            y = randint(0, self.gridSize-1)
        return (x, y)

    def findWinner(self, index, grid):
        # Row
        found = True
        for j in range(self.gridSize-1):
            if (grid[index[0]][j] != grid[index[0]][j+1] or grid[index[0]][j] == 0):
                found = False
                break
        if (found):
            self.winner = self.turn
            return self.turn
        
        # Column
        found = True
        for i in range(self.gridSize-1):
            if (grid[i][index[1]] != grid[i+1][index[1]] or grid[i][index[1]] == 0):
                found = False
                break
        if (found):
            self.winner = self.turn
            return self.turn
        
        # Top Left to Bottom Right Diagonal
        if (index[0] == index[1]):
            found = True
            for i in range(self.gridSize-1):
                if (grid[i][i] != grid[i+1][i+1] or grid[i][i] == 0):
                    found = False
                    break
            if (found):
                self.winner = self.turn
                return self.turn

        # Top Right to Bottom Left Diagonal
        if (index[0] + index[1] == self.gridSize-1):
            found = True
            for i in range(self.gridSize-1):
                if (grid[self.gridSize-i-1][i] != grid[self.gridSize-i-2][i+1] or grid[self.gridSize-i-1][i] == 0):
                    found = False
                    break
            if (found):
                self.winner = self.turn
                return self.turn
            
        
        tie = True
        for i in range(self.gridSize):
            for j in range(self.gridSize):
                if (grid[i][j] == 0):
                    tie = False
        
        if (tie):
            self.winner = 0
            return 0

        return None
```

The grid is represented as a 2d array, with each element being either a -1 for O, 1 for X and 0 for nothing. The player is 1 and the computer is -1. Who's turn it is is represented as a -1 or 1, corresponding to O or X. If anyone is able to find where the error in my code is that would be a great.

Comment: I think your Minimax.py code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I see two troubles :

a) the two following conditions are the same in minimax

```
    if (winner == -1):
       return winner - depth, currIndex
    elif (winner == -1):
       return winner + depth, currIndex
```

b) When you return `bestIndex`, you actually return the winning move, the one that completes a line or a row or a diagonal, at one of the leaves of the game tree. What you really want is the *next* move to play. Write instead `bestIndex = (i, j)` in the condition `if eval > evalLimit`

I didn't check for everything but that is a good start. Run your code at depth=1 or 2 with many printf inside the minimax function, and look at the different moves, with the corresponding score, if they look correct or not.